# Vagrant (Homestead) sync folders and SSH access from another computer in LAN

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

That's the situation:

- Computer #1 (Ubuntu) with running Vagrant (Homestead) on it, has a ~/Work host folder, that synced with /home/vagrant/work VM's folder and nginx on 192.168.10.10 in host
- Developing computer #2 (Mac) in the same LAN, with PhpStorm on it

So I want to have a vagrant real-time sync folder on Computer #2 folder (for example, /home/Users/admin/Work) to VM's folder and nginx site access for PhpStorm develop

*(know, my english is bad)*

Comment: you would need to mount `/home/Users/admin/Work` (comp2) as ~/Work folder (comp1) using network drive (something like http://blog.ibd.com/sysadmin/bonjour-avahi-netatalk-to-share-files-files-between-ubuntu-10-4-mac-os-x/) or samba ... but even though it could work, it would be horribly slow